# Гамбургер меню по умолчанию открыто

Tags: jquery, адаптивная-верстка, menu

Есть гамбургер меню и при открытии страницы меню уже открыто, и только после перезагрузки страницы меню в закрытом состоянии. Не могу понять почему оно изначально открыто.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 900) {
    $(".nav-info").hide();
    $(".hamburger").on("click touch", function() {
      $(".nav-info").slideToggle();
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-info">
  <nav>
    <ul class="navigation">
      <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Услуги</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Галерея</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Отзывы</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="phone-social">
    <ul class="call">
      <li><a href="#callme" class="callme-pp"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="tel:+888888888888">+88 (888) 888 88 88</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="social">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Я обратил внимание, что у меня в целом идёт проблема с подгрузкой скриптов и не могу понять в чем дело.

Comment: Возможно что-то с проверкой ширины
Могу предположить, что у Вас ширина окна сначала больше 900 и когда вы сужаете окно, меню остаётся открытым.

Добавьте событие с проверкой ширины на изменение размера окна браузера.

Comment: я обратил внимание что у меня в целом идет проблема с подгружением скриптов и не могу понять в чем дело. Можете помочь взглянуть? https://github.com/Bohdan29/Renessans-Event

Comment: К сожалению, я не силён в файловых "взаимоотношениях", а в том, что я увидел, не нашёл ничего необычного

Comment: у меня эта меню еще и сворачивается тут же после клика на расскрытие. Не знаете почему так происходит и как добавить событие на отслеживание ширины? в js\jquery не силен

Comment: Сейчас ошибки я не вижу

Comment: а как добавить событие отслеживания ширины?

Comment: Добавьте проверку ширины в `$(window).resize(function() {...})` и оно будет проверять каждый раз, когда пользователь изменит размер окна. А так же совет, скрывайте и открывайте меню с помощью добавления/удаление специального класса для меню, а не с помощью JS

Comment: добавил, теперь скрипт не срабатывает

Comment: Ахаха... Ой, не знаю тогда)